# Excel - Check 2 table list if its the same value

Tags: excel-formula

This may be a weird request. I'm dealing about 100-250 rows for my case.

A simplified example screenshot:

[image]

I am using vlookup (column `G` & `H`) to assign the values based on Master sheet table.
But I was wondering if there is a way to include a formula for "checker" column to indicate if the values from vlookup are assigned correctly in `G` and `H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$5,E1,$B$1:$B$5,F1,$C$1:$C$5,G1)>0,"OK","Nope")
```

or without `countifs`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$5=E1)*($B$1:$B$5=F1)*($C$1:$C$5=G1))>0,"OK","Nope")
```

[image]

This doesn' check for duplicates in the first list. A simple `countif` could do that job

Comment: I tried the countifs method on my data and it shows "Nope" for some strange reasons.

But Sumproduct works tho

Comment: Maybe you are working with an older version of excel.